# How can I execute the rolling_curl function

Tags: php, function, curl

I will execute this function: 
`function rolling_curl($urls, $callback, $custom_options = null)` from http://www.onlineaspect.com/2009/01/26/how-to-use-curl_multi-without-blocking/

I will not use the Rolling Curl PHP Libary, I will use only this funtion.

This is what I have tried:

```
<?php
require('Requests.php');

$urls = array("http://www.google.com/",
              "http://www.facebook.com/",
              "http://www.yahoo.com/");


$callback = function($output, $info)
{
    print_r($output);

};

rolling_curl();
?>
```

The "Requests.php" ist the 
`function rolling_curl($urls, $callback, $custom_options = null)` from http://www.onlineaspect.com/2009/01/26/how-to-use-curl_multi-without-blocking/

This error I resive:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function rolling_curl(), 0 passed in /var/www/vhosts/example.php on line 15 and at least 2 expected in /var/www/vhosts/Requests.php:2 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/vhosts/example.php(15): rolling_curl() #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/vhosts/Requests.php on line 2
```

Comment: Shouldn't the last line of your code be `rolling_curl($urls,$callback);`?

Comment: I think you are right, but it doen´t work.

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, is it the same error or something new?

Comment: Its the same error